# Azure AD B2C Simple Username authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am having an issue authenticating users for a external, non-cloud ASP.NET  application that is going to be secured via our B2C tenant using a simple username (i.e. not email address).

I have imported the usernames to B2C using the Graph API and set the SignInName type to be "userName" on each account.  The Azure AD B2C Identity Provider is set to "Username" and I have created a sign-in policy where the identity provider is set to "Local Account SignIn" and tied it to my B2C application. If I click the "Run Now" button on the policy, it takes me to the Azure login screen and I can enter one of the imported usernames/passwords and it authenticates and routes me to the application URL.  This is the desired behavior.

HOWEVER, if when I execute my external app I get transferred to the Azure B2C login screen as expected, but it requires me to enter either a valid email address or telephone number. It will not allow the local B2C username. Seems something is disconnected in the sign-in policy for the application.

Can anyone offer a suggestion why the login page will not accept the simple username?

Comment: Could you make sure the same policy is used in both cases?

Comment: Please add more details, code snippets, what do requests look like, screenshots of the error, etc, otherwise it's hard to help out.

Answer (score 0):

I guees this is a bit late? perhas other are looking for this.
Azure AD B2C can be use email OR localAccount for authentication. You need to set the "identity providers" to localAccounts: 
[image]

Note: in odrer to create local accounts you need to set "creationType": "LocalAccount" in the JSON to create local account users.